# How to display an initially-hidden map created with Gmaps4rails v2? (Gmaps.loadMaps removed in V2)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

In my app I create a map using the gmaps4rails gem. The map is displayed in a fancybox popup when the user opens the fancybox.

The div containing the map is hidden initially, when the map is created on page load, via the usual

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap(...);
```

The problem is the map is incomplete, presumably because it's hidden when created. There was a simple fix with the V1 gem, using `.loadMaps()`

With the V1 gem, I could call `Gmaps.loadMaps();` in the fancybox callback that is executed when fancybox is displayed:

```
  $("a.fancybox_map").fancybox(
  { 
    'openEffect' : 'elastic',
    'closeEffect' : 'elastic',
    'scrolling' : 'yes',
    'autoHeight' : true,
    'afterShow' : function() { 
      Gmaps.loadMaps(); // doesn't work - removed from V2?
    }
  });
```

Is there another way in the V2 gem to reload or refresh the map?

Comment: try to do `handler.buildMap(...)` instead of `Gmaps.loadMaps()`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Ben! However fancybox cannot dynamically adjust its size on the fly to accommodate a variable-size map (since it might have directions) which is why (using your V1 gem) I built the map on page load, then reload the already built map when the fancybox is opened.

Comment: not sure I understand why the map could have different dimensions. But calling `handler.buildMap(...)` twice is the same as calling `Gmaps.loadMaps()` twice

Comment: I'll give it another try - thank you!